# php code not working, what is wrong with the codes?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am trying to fix some codes, but can't find it out.
i hope you guys can help me!

errors:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home//public_html/wp-content/plugins//view/import.php on line 148

```
<?php foreach ($product['sku_products']['attributes'] as $attr): ?>
```

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home//public_html/wp-content/plugins//view/import.php on line 209

```
<?php foreach ($product['sku_products']['variations'] as $i => $var):
 ?>
```

thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) expects argument should be array or object

In your case `$product['sku_products']['attributes']` could be either `null` or `false` or not `array`

So what you can do is as below using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

```
if(isset($product['sku_products']['attributes']) && is_array($product['sku_products']['attributes']))
{
   foreach ($product['sku_products']['attributes'] as $attr):
}
```

**Modify your view like below**

```
<?php if(isset($product['sku_products']['attributes']) && is_array($product['sku_products']['attributes'])):?>
   <?php foreach ($product['sku_products']['attributes'] as $attr): ?>
          <p>Your contents goes here</p>
   <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Here is example for testing**

```
$ php -r 'foreach(null as $test){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1

$ php -r 'foreach(false as $test){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1

$ php -r '$p="string";foreach($p as $test){}'
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: @vineanimals : did you understand what could be the cause for the error you mentioned from anyone example given here